# 2d Array with Rectangle() grid

Tags: java, arrays, awt

I am trying to make a grid, using a 2d array list, I want to make it with Rectangles so I can use .intersects with it, I also need it to be 95 x 95 and 95 apart, this is what I have so far but its not working because of an error.

```
    public static Rectangle[][] walls;
    public static void walls() {
    int wallsY = 0, wallsX =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            //shapeList.add(new Rectangle(wallsX, wallsY, 95, 95));
            walls[i][j] = new Rectangle(wallsX,wallsY,95,95);
            wallsY += 95;
            wallsX += 95;

        }
    }
```

then i use:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
        for(int j =0; j < walls.length; j++){
            if (intersectsBox(playerRectangle(), walls[i][j])) {
                isInsideWalls = true;
            }   
        }
     }
```

to check if they are intersecting. But I keep getting an error which is right here:

> `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at bombermangame.Game.walls(Game.java:165)  at
>   bombermangame.Game.(Game.java:62)   at
>   bombermangame.Menu.actionPerformed(Menu.java:98)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialized walls. Prior to your for loop `for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)`, add:

```
walls = new Rectangle[7][7];
```

I put 7 and 7 in there because that is what it appears the dimensions will be.

Comment: Thanks, i tried moving the location of when its loaded into the game to the back, and it worked, I also needed to add this